# CGAL join after difference

Tags: cgal

I have a problem with CGAL, I divide a polygon (Polygon_with_holes_2) in different parts using intersection and difference functions and then I make a dissolve with the join function. But after using difference, the result of join function is not right, some lines hadn't been cut and it provokes a lot of errors.
Does anybody knows how to solve this? It's a big problem and I've tried some solutions but anything works.

Comment: Do you still have the issue, after a month? Can you explain what sort of error you get after the join?

Comment: Sorry! Now it works. The problem was that I used my own structures between CGAL operations, so it was losing precission. Thank you very much for your interest.

Comment: @user3062433 could you either post an answer as to how you solved the problem or remove the question?

Comment: I've already posted how I solved it. The problem was that I was using my own structures (with float type) between join and difference operations, because of that, I was losing precission, so the vertex didn't match and strange lines appeared everywhere. I've tried to update the title to add [SOLVED] but it didn't work, I'll try again. Thank you!!

Comment: Do not add "solved" or similar to your question. If you wish to mark a question as resolved to your satisfaction you may accept an answer. If you found your own solution you may post it as an *answer* with sufficient detail that it may help future readers. It would be great to see some code in both the question and your solution.

Comment: Can you please post an official answer to your question, and self-accept it? That will close the question.

Comment: Done, thank you!! It was my first time. Sorry.

Comment: @user3062433 I understand. That is why moderators (those with the ♦ next to their names), and even regular users, post comments to help newcomers. I was a newcomer not so long ago! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using my own structures (with float type) between join and difference operations, because of that, I was losing precission, so the vertex didn't match and strange lines appeared everywhere. I've tried to update the title to add [SOLVED] but it didn't work, I'll try again. Thank you!!